# Get latest records in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently i am working on elastic search for my project. I need to display my records(latest first). i am using sort technique. 
`"sort" => array(array('created_date' => 'desc')),`

and my mapping everything in string. `"products":{

```
"properties":{
    "add_by":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "categories":{
        "properties":{
            "category_name":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "id":{
                "type":"string"
            }
        }
    },
    "company_logo":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "company_name":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "created_date":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "id":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "industries":{
        "properties":{
            "id":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "industry_name":{
                "type":"string"
            }
        }
    },
    "location":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "location_latitude":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "location_longitude":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "num_of_employees":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "practice_areas":{
        "properties":{
            "id":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "practice_area_image":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "practice_area_name":{
                "type":"string"
            }
        }
    },
    "product_description":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "product_image":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "product_name":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "product_rating":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "status":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "updated_date":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "user_id":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "user_sub_type":{
        "type":"string"
    },
    "user_type":{
        "type":"string"
    }
}
```

}`
i think i might me update my mapping like id and created_date(both are update to integer and timestamp). Please help me how to update mapping for my-type(product). Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ->Which elasticsearch version you are running?
- ->Latest version doesn't support Updating mapping type.
- ->If you want to change mapping,you need to create new index with new mapping and copy data from old index to new index
- ->Another Process:insert new field with new mapping and use copy_to in mappings.

  example:

  ```
              'id' => [
                     'type' => 'string',

                     'copy_to' => 'combined'
                 ],
                 'newid' => [
                     'type' => 'integer',

                 ],

              'created_at' => [
                     'type' => 'string',

                     'copy_to' => 'date'
                 ],
            'date' => [
                     'type' => 'date',
                     'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',

                 ],
  ```

Comment: Currently  i am using elastic 2.0 version.

Comment: i version 2.0 updating mapping type is not supported. [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)

Comment: Version 2.0 doesn't support update mapping.read update maaping in link provided.[check here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)

Comment: i am using chorme postman, to creat new index and mapping with type. using PUT. after PUT mapping gets acknowledment: true. then after i want to check my mappings in index using curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_mapping or http://localhost:9200/vendors_new/_mappings are using, then i got {"vendors_new":{"mappings":{}}} like this. i am totally confused. whether my mapping inserted or not please help me.

Comment: this follows my mapping {"mappings":{"users":{"_all":{"enabled":false},"properties":{"company_name":{"type":"string"},"company_description":{"type":"string"},"company_logo":{"type":"string"},"user_rating":{"type":"float"},"user_reviews":{"type":"integer"},"user_sub_type":{"type":"integer"},"id":{"type":"integer"},"first_name":{"type":"string"},"last_name":{"type":"string"},"username":{"type":"string"},"email":{"type":"string"},"created_date":{"type":"date","format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"},"num_of_employees":{"type":"integer"}}}}}

Comment: change enabled true and check once

Comment: Are you using it in php to create elasticsearch index

Comment: i am using chrome potman for creating index and mapping, and insert data using php $this->elasticsearch->add();

Comment: yes, i create index using php, like
$config['es_server'] = 'http://localhost:9200';
$config['index'] = 'my_index';  at this time i am not create any mapping.. once i researched, create mapping at time of index creation only. that's i am using chrome postman to create index with mapping.

Comment: finally i got it, and working nicely. Just I arrange My Json Data and PUT the data using $this->elasticsearch->create($data). this turns to create new index with mapping.